# Using same function inside multiple tabs

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a php script that renders several tabs.

Within each tab is a code that is repeated within several tabs and this makes the update process difficult.

**example:**

```
<div id="1" class="tabcontent">
<?php 
if (!empty( $_POST['newtags'] ) ) {
wp_set_post_tags( $post->ID, $_POST['newtags'], true );
} ?>
</div>

<div id="2" class="tabcontent">
<?php 
if (!empty( $_POST['h2'])){ // if the input field is not empty
update_post_meta($post->ID, 'description', $concatenated_description, $description_field );
}?>
</div>

<div id="3" class="tabcontent">
    <?php 
if (!empty( $_POST['newtags'] ) ) {
wp_set_post_tags( $post->ID, $_POST['newtags'], true );
} ?>
</div>
```

In order to facilitate the update, I would like to know if it's possible to make something like this:

**put functions above the script like this:**

```
function set_newtags() {
 if (!empty( $_POST['newtags'] ) ) {
wp_set_post_tags( $post->ID, $_POST['newtags'], true );
  }
}

function set_newmeta() {
 if (!empty( $_POST['h2'])){ // if the input field is not empty
update_post_meta($post->ID, 'description', $concatenated_description, $description_field );
  }
}
```

(this way, I just have to update one function and not several copies of the code inside multiple tabs)

**and than, call them within the respective tab, like this:**

```
<div id="1" class="tabcontent">
<?php set_newtags() ?>
</div>

<div id="2" class="tabcontent">
<?php set_newmeta() ?>
</div>

<div id="3" class="tabcontent">
<?php set_newtags() ?>
</div>
```

**Problem?** This is not working.

What am'I doing wrong?

Comment: what if you use `return` inside of those functions...like `return update_post_....`